# Tkinter window not closing

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a server with Tkinter where it asks for the IP address you want to start the server on. when you jit enter it's supposed to close the window and start the server but the window doesn't close it just crashes(the server also starts though).
my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket, threading, sys
import tkinter as tk

def sub(self):
    global ip
    ip = e1.get()
    rw.quit()


rw = tk.Tk()
rw.title("IP")
rw.configure(bg="grey14")
rw.geometry("250x50")

hostname = socket.gethostname()
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

e1 = tk.Entry(rw)
e1.bind("<Return>", sub)
e1.insert(0, IPAddr)
e1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

b1 = tk.Button(rw, text="Submit", command=sub).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

rw.mainloop()
```

please help!
(the server code is left out because StackOverflow says I'm not allowed to have that much code and this little text, but basically it starts another loop that accepts the clients)

Comment: maybe the loop is the reason y it doesnt close properly, try to include that code too. Mayb remove some non imp part from this

Comment: Also, try saying `rw.destroy()` instead of `rw.quit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this command instead:

```
rw.destroy()
```

rw.quit() just bypasses the rw.mainloop() so that rw.mainloop() will still be running in the background. rw.destroy() stops it.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `sub(self)`and on your `Button`you have written just `command=sub`
So you have to write their

```py
self.b1=tk.Button(rw,text="Submit",command=sub).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
```

It's working I have run it

Comment: This is false: _"root.mainloop() will still be running in background if quit() command is executed."_. `quit` stops mainloop. There is nothing running in the background.

Comment: `command=lambda:[self.sub]` is wrong as `self.sub` is not defined.  Even though it is defined, it is just a reference and `self.sub()` will not be executed.